# How to get a value from map

Tags: go

#### Problem

Fetching data from map

#### Data Format

```
res = map[Event_dtmReleaseDate:2009-09-15 00:00:00 +0000 +00:00 Trans_strGuestList:<nil> strID:TSTB]
```

#### Note

How to get the following value from the above result

1. `Event_dtmReleaseDate`
2. `strID`
3. `Trans_strGuestList`

**What i tried:**

1. `res.Map("Event_dtmReleaseDate");`

> Error : res.Map undefined (type map[string]interface {} has no field or method Map)

2. `res.Event_dtmReleaseDate;`

> Error: v.id undefined (type map[string]interface {} has no field or method id)

Comment: Is map correctly initialized? Because your Data Format is not a correct go syntax. If the map is `map[string]something` you can access the elements using `val := res["Event_dtmReleaseDate"]`

Comment: Gosh I had this opened up and forgot about it. When I returned to the tab I thought the title was "How to get value from a nap" and I was 100% prepared to answer that

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Your variable is a `map[string]interface {}` which means the key is a string but the value can be anything. In general the way to access this is:

```
mvVar := myMap[key].(VariableType)
```

Or in the case of a string value:

```
id  := res["strID"].(string)
```

Note that this will panic if the type is not correct or the key does not exist in the map, but I suggest you read more about Go maps and type assertions.

Read about maps here: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps

And about type assertions and interface conversions here: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions

The safe way to do it without a chance to panic is something like this:

```
var id string
var ok bool
if x, found := res["strID"]; found {
     if id, ok = x.(string); !ok {
        //do whatever you want to handle errors - this means this wasn't a string
     }
} else {
   //handle error - the map didn't contain this key
}
```

Comment: Perhaps something was different back in 2014, but these days if a key doesn't exist, map access will not panic, it will return a zero (or zero-equivalent) value.

Answer (score 17):

In general to get value from map you have to do something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{"foo": "bar"}
    value, exists := m["foo"]
    // In case when key is not present in map variable exists will be false.
    fmt.Printf("key exists in map: %t, value: %v \n", exists, value)
}
```

Result will be:

```
key exists in map: true, value: bar
```